# scala play 2.5 testing views that needs implicit Flash

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, specs2

How can i test a twirl view that require an implicit flash variables?

e.g.:

test

```
"render view" in new WithApplication {
      contentAsString(views.html.index()) must contain("Hello")
    }
```

twirl view:

```
@()(implicit flash: Flash)
<div>
  @if(flash.get("error").isDefined) {
    flash.get("error").getOrElse(""))
 }
</div>
<p> Hello! </p>
```

in the test above, how can i pass an `implicit flash:Flash` value/variable?

Do I need to inject in `WithApplication` or extending that `trait`?

Comment: You can pass implicits explicitly. http://ideone.com/jZ86AH

Comment: Also side-note:  If you're checking `flash.get("error").isDefined`, you'll never hit the "orElse" part of `getOrElse`.

Comment: I didn't get the side-note. that @if is from the play documentation.

Comment: I understand that. `flash.get("error")` will return an `Option[T]`. `getOrElse` will never fail because you've checked if `flash.get("error")` is defined. You can use `flash("error")` or `flash.get("error").get`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enough to:

```
import play.api.mvc.Flash

"render view" in new WithApplication {
      contentAsString(views.html.index()(new Flash()) must contain("Hello")
    }
```